# VPS в роcсии

Tags: vps

Как житель Украины, не ознакомлен с российскими хостинг-провайдерами в принципе. Посоветуйте возможность арендовать недорогой VPS(ориентировочно 250р.) сервер.

Что необходимо:

- ОС Debian
- PHP 5.3.x

Пока за дешево для старта проекта.

P.S. Понимаю что вопрос скорее всего на РутКод, но так как я тут не первый день, невостребованность Рута меня пугает.

P.P.S Понимаю что можно загуглить, но хочется рассчитывать еще и на опыт здешних форумчан  которые тесно связаны с арендой VPS.

**UPD:**

Может кому интересно, в украине я юзаю этот [thehost](http://thehost.com.ua/vps_vds/plans)

тьфу тьфу тьфу не воспримите за рекламу)

Comment: Хостьте лучше в Зимбабве. А то придут фэсэбэшники Ваш сервер изымать изымать за то, что на нем ссылки на нелицензионный контент, а Вы даже грудью даже прикрыть его не сможете, так как в Украине находитесь.

Comment: Дельная мысль) роскомнадзор работает жестко) на хабре начитан)

Comment: @ReinRaus, я бы грудь не подставлял, а то пробить могут. Но таки да, для не совсем "правильного" контента, с точки зрения властей, лучше хоститься где на нейтральной территории. В другом случае (*мое личное мнение*), выбирать надо регион, где живут те, на кого расчитан контентент данного сайта, а еще - многие выбирают сервера в Германии.

Comment: @Deonis в том то и дело что контингент на рос. федерацию рассчитан. Это мой личный проект без заказчиков и т.п. хотелось бы чтобы трафик соответствовал расположению сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan), тогда посмотрите [InterServer](http://interserver.ru/vds.html). Там относительно не дорого (от 5$ месяц + скидка за больший период оплаты). Правда на дешевых тарифах, параметры, мягко говоря, не ахти...

Comment: Преобразовал в ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Недавно наткнулся на провайдера [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com), размещение, если смотреть по удаленности от России, ближайшее в Амстердаме. Взял пока самый дешевый тариф, тестирую в течении месяца, всем доволен. Также вроде можно с промо-кодом `SSDLINUX` получить при регистрации 10$ на счет.

Answer (score 0):

santrex.net (Есть Russia) 
inferno.name на любой вкус есть, по-моему даже США есть.